# How do pupils solve 2nd degree equations in Germany? (different from Spain)

Tags: problem-solving, quadratics

I'm from Spain and in Spain the undergraduate pupils learn to solve a 2nd degree (i.e. quadratic) equation using the formula

$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

but years ago I had a colleague who did secondary school in Germany and he solved this kind of equation using another formula/method.

Someone could tell me about the method taught to German pupils to solve 2nd degree equations? Using formulas, not graphical solutions.

Thank you.

Comment: ... why not ask him?

Comment: You can see this Wikipedia page.It may contains the answer of your question:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Solving_the_quadratic_equation .

Comment: He certainly knew this formula, it is known in german as the "mitternachtsformel". The method in question is probably the method of completing the square

Comment: I think that mathematics for undergraduates is taught in pretty much the same manner world wide. At this level of complexity, if some (unlikely) brilliant breakthrough occurred, then everybody would immediately adopt and merge it into their study programs (as is the case in almost every other cultural aspect of life, such as food, clothes, music, etc). So it's more likely that you've missed that class in Spain were they taught the "German" method. Aside that point, @ZevChonoles, the question says **"years ago"**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a German exchange student and he also thought our quadratic equation was complicated. He learned it this way:
$$x = \frac12\left(-p \pm \sqrt{p^2 - 4q}\right)$$
where $p=b/a$ and $q=c/a$. So basically it's the same formula, but you divide everything first by the leading coefficient $a$ to simplify it instead of at the end. Or you can divide the $p$ by the $2$ right in the original equation.

I will attach a picture he sent me. Just make sure you divide everything by $a$ first so there is no leading coefficient in front of your $x$.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The other two common methods for solving a second degree equation are:

- Completing the square (which is essentially equivalent to using the aforementioned formula: this is basically how the formula is derived):

$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$
$$x^2+2\frac{b}{2a}x+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}=-\frac{c}{a}+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}$$
$$(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$$
$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

- If $x_1,x_2$ are the two solutions of the equation, it is known that

$$x_1+x_2=-\frac{b}{a}$$
$$x_1\cdot x_2=\frac{c}{a}$$
     This system of equation is easily solved by substitution or by any other mean.

I believe that your German friend might be referring to the latter method. Pupils are usually introduced to polynomial factorization before studying equations. Once one knows how to factorize a second degree polynomial properly, solving the equation is a piece of cake.

Comment: Than you, it´s possible that this one were the method of my friend. I´m going to wait a few days for many more proposes, but I will probably mark this one as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes :-) Thank you @Shauntelle . Finally I found the paper where the notes are. It´s the same that you posted.
[image]